# Can Spirits of Man with the Innate Spell power use Alchemical Preparations known by the Summoner

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

The text in the rule book states that Spirits of Man have the power:

> Innate Spell (any one spell known by the summoner; Force is limited to the spirit's Magic)

The question is whether spells taken as Alchemical Preparations count as "spells known by the summoner". I feel that the answer is probably yes, due to the fact that it still refers to "spells" when describing the process of creating Alchemy, and also this line in the "Choose a Spell" section of the Alchemy rules:

> Spells used in preparations are different versions
>   of the Sorcery spells listed on p. 283, but have the same
>   effect, Drain Value, keywords, and so on as those spells.
>   You learn the alchemical versions of these spells separately
>   from Sorcery spells, but the Karma cost is the same.

Are there any definitions of what constitutes a "Spell" for this purpose, or other rules that clarify the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a disclaimer, I have yet to find *explicit* wording but here is what I've extrapolated from the book:

Under the description for "Innate Spell" it says

> To use this power effectively, the critter has to have the Spellcasting skill.

Since it relies on the Spellcasting Skill, I do not believe and Alchemical Preparation counts as that relates to the Alchemy skill, and they are very specifically separated for learning them by skill (spells, rites, and alchemy). The Spellcasting Skill also specifically states knowing how to channel Mana. So...

**No given creature should have Innate Spell for an Alchemical Preparation**

Comment: This seems like a sensible conclusion to me. Thank you very much.